# log4j2 configuration XML file for 2 log files with new folder each run

Tags: java, logging, junit, log4j2

I am a little new to log4j2. I am looking for how I can configure the log4j2.xml file for our test automation framework. What we desire is two log files. One being non-technical and one with all the technical details, like stack trace information. This means direct INFO and ERROR messages to one file. All messages will direct to the other file. So, the one file will contain everything the other one does and more.

The other thing we desire, is everytime we run the tests it will create a new set of logs inside a folder with a time stamp.

For example

Directory Structure

> - Application Name
>
>   - 2015-12-02 16:52:30
>
>     - logTechnical.log (ALL logs)
>     - logSimple.log (INFO and ERROR)
>   - 2015-12-02 16:52:30
>
>     - logTechnical.log (ALL logs)
>     - logSimple.log (INFO and ERROR)

The other thing if possible in log4j. I think a batch file or custom code may be needed. But if we can have it keep only the 5 latest logs, so the server doesn't get messy. We don't want to use a rolling log file for this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following configuration creates the directory and files, but does not delete the old directories:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <File name="Simple" 
          fileName="app/${date:yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss}/logSimple.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
      <Filters>
        <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
        <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
        <ThresholdFilter level="warn" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
        <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
      </Filters>
    </File>
    <File name="Technical" 
          fileName="app/${date:yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss}/logTechnical.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="all">
      <AppenderRef ref="Simple" />
      <AppenderRef ref="Technical" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked just as I hoped.

Comment: There is one other thing, with this I am noticing. Is there a way to force the log file to be created? What I am finding is if a Warn message for example comes through, then at a later time a INFO message comes through, it creates two separate folders, since they logs occurred at different times. Is there a way to force log4j to create a blank log file, so I can always have both log files in the same folder? Thanks

Comment: Empty files are created in each run (each in a separate JVM, log4j2 configuration is loaded each time) when no message is recorded. I'm on Windows.

Comment: Okay cool thanks. It was just odd, because I had one instance where it created them in separate folders.

Comment: Hi again, I am also using doing tests with Selenium, and what I desire is to store screenshots in the same directory with the logs, for that current run. Do you know how I can either get the directory for the logs or get the time/date used for the directory name? Thanks

Comment: Hi, @Codemiester Yes, it is possible. Create a new question with this. :-)